# Firebase Hosting, disable HTTPS?

Tags: http, firebase, https, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

Is there any way to disable HTTPS with Firebase hosting?

The reason I need this, is that, I've built a site that lets you embed iframes from other sites, and security rules disallow me from embedding an HTTP frame inside of my HTTPS site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  All traffic coming into and going out of Google is encrypted.

Comment: But the ssl is issued to firebaseapp.com and has conflict with other domains.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, I am working on a very small IoT device that communicates with our own server, and with a Google Cloud Function. I was thinking about using Firebase to handle the cloud function instead, but we don't have the space on the device for doing the calculations required for SSL. So, that won't work for my use case.

Comment: Hi @BiagioArobba, ironically I am in the same situation, and although Firebase is an excellent product, lending itself as the perfect IoT platform, the HTTPS requirements kills all ambitions. No use building millions of new devices just to be able to run on Firebase. Did you ever solve the issue, or did you use another provider/sollution?

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) written: "After we verify domain ownership, we provision an SSL certificate for your domain and deploy it across our global CDN. This process can take several hours". Seems the issue will be gone after 24 hours.