# How to disable TLS V1.0 in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a requirement to disable TLS V1.0 for my app hosted in firebase.
As I am new to firebase hosting, looking for some help in disabling the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to disable TLS v1.0 (or SSL/[HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413014/firebase-hosting-disable-https) in general) on Firebase Hosting.